# InputMismatchException in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am getting a InputMismatchException error, although everything should be working as intended. I only get the error when the user has to enter an int value (setAge). Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Withdraw myAccount = new Withdraw();

    Customer Jack = new Customer();
    out.println("Enter your full name");
    String FullName = keyboard.next();
    Jack.setName(FullName);

    out.println("Enter your address");
    String Address = keyboard.next();
    Jack.setAddress(Address);

    // I GET THE ERROR IN THE LINES BELOW.
    out.println("Enter your age");
    int age = keyboard.nextInt();
    Jack.setAge(age);
```

Here's the code for the Customer class

```
public class Customer {

String name;
String address;
int age;

public void setName(String NameIn) {
    name = NameIn;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setAddress(String addressIn) {
    address = addressIn;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAge(int ageIn) {
    age = ageIn;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess it's because the input isn't an int. i.e. someone entered a non-numeric character(s).

Comment: Nope, I get the error before I even get the chance to enter anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) uses whitespaces as word delimiters so any addresses containing these characters will cause the input to be passed through to the next `Scanner` input statement, namely `nextInt` in this case.

Therefore use `nextLine` which reads the entire line input:

```
String address = keyboard.nextLine();
```

The same will be required for `fullName` should any whitespaces exist in that variable.

Aside: Java naming conventions show that variables start with *lowercase* letters, e.g. `address` and `fullName`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the whole line as Reimeus suggested, you can parse the `String` to a `int` using

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(line);
```